# Login always fails in my Sql based visual basic simple login application

Tags: sql, vb.net

I tried to create a login page in VISUAL BASIC. But the problem is that the login always fails . My program is connected to my sql database and though my password and username is correct through text boxes the output is always login fail!! and I don't know where is screwed up .

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class login
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim connection1 As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server = VAIOO-PC ; Database = forum ; Integrated Security= true "}
        Dim sqlcommand As New SqlCommand(" Select * from username where username= @username and password =@password", connection1)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textboxuser.Text
        sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textboxpassword.Text

        Dim sqldtaadpt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand) 'passes the command to via the adapter

        Dim table As New DataTable()
        If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
            MsgBox("USERNAME or THE PASSWORD IS INCORRECT")
        Else
            MsgBox("login successful")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to fill the datatable.

Use Fill method of DataAdapter.

```
sqlcommand.Open()
sqldtaadpt.Fill(table)
```

To get a full example, look at SqlCommand class help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx